# Approximation to a parametrized integral

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

Consider the following integral:

> $$ I_1(r)=\int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-\sqrt{r-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r-x^2}} \frac{1} {(x^2+y^2) \log^2\big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\big)}\,dy\,dx.$$

I am not able to evaluate these integral in terms of $r$ explicitly. However, using Matlab, I managed to evaluate the integral for different values of $r$.

The values are as follows:

$ I_1 (0.036)= 1.4283.$

$ I_1 (0.018)= 1.1937.$

$ I_1 (0.009)= 1.0227.$

$ I_1 (0.0045)=0.8920.$

$\vdots$

$ I_1 (0.0011)=0.7048$

The sequence is decreasing as r decreases. What can we say about $$\lim_{r \to 0} I_1 (r)?$$

Answer (score 1):

By a change of variable $(x,y)=\rho(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ you get the integral

$$2\pi\int_0^r\frac{d\rho}{\rho\log^2(2/\rho)},$$
which converges only if $0\leq r <2$, in which case the value is $\frac{2\pi}{\log(2/r)}$, (note that $\frac{d}{d\rho}\left[\frac{1}{\log(2/\rho)}\right]=\frac{1}{\rho\log^2(2/\rho)}$) which tends to zero as $r\to 0$, in agreement with your numerical results.

Comment: The values don't match at all. The question considers the natural log, are you mentioning the same in answer? Also, can you tell me where I can find this result?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the natural logarithm. I don't know where you can find this result. I just made the calculation 12 minutes ago. Do you follow the calculation of the integral in polar coordinates?

Comment: Polar  coordinates is the natural way. But how did you evaluate that integral and got $\frac{2\pi}{\log{\frac{2}{r}}}$?

Comment: Note that the derivative of $\frac{1}{\log(2/\rho)}$ is equal to the expression under the integral sign, so it can be calculated immediately.

Comment: Yeah. I just figured it out by myself as well. Thanks a lot. But do you know why the values from matlab are not matching?

Comment: I have no idea why the values don't match with matlab.